# Adding a horizontal line in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to draw a horizontal thick line for separating rows in report based on one column values. I.e., if previous and current value is the same I want to draw a horizontal line. 
For that I wrote jquery coding its working fine in mozilla but not in IE . What mistake did I make?

```
var a = 1;
$(".calbody tr td:nth-child(8) a").each(function() {
    var foo = "<hr width=2000% ;'>";
    if (a === 1) {
        $(this).parents("tr:first").before(foo);
    }
    if (a != 1) {
        var b = $(this).text();  
        if (a != b) {
            $(this).parents("tr:first").before(foo);    
        }
    }
    a = $(this).text();  
});
```

Comment: <hr width=2000% ;'> should be : <hr width='2000% ;'>? you have single qoute only at the end?

Comment: There should be *no* `hr` elements inside of a `table` unless they're inside of a `td` or `th`: the only valid children of a `table` element are: `thead`,`tbody`, `tfoot`, `tr`, `caption` and `colgroup`. Reference: [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Ftable).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var foo = "<hr width='2000%'>";
```